# multer diskStorage is not a function

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

**Hola a todos, espero estén bien.**

Soy nuevo en estas cosas de NodeJS y Express disculpen mi ignorancia.

Estoy tratando de subir una o varias imágenes a mi base en MongoBD mediante un api.

En mi Backend estoy utilizando Multer v.1.0 para subir las imágenes pero me sale el siguiente mensaje de error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el multer declarado de la siguiente forma no se que estoy haciendo mal.

**Lo tengo dentro de una carpeta llamada routes como project.js.**

```js
'use strict'

var express = require('express');
var ProjectController = require('../controllers/project');
var router = express.Router();


var crypto = require('crypto')
var multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({

    destination(req, file, cb) {
  
      cb(null, './uploads/albums');
  
    },
  
    filename(req, file = {}, cb) {
  
      const { originalname } = file;
  
      const fileExtension = (originalname.match(/\.+[\S]+$/) || [])[0];
  
      cb(null, `${file.fieldname}__${Date.now()}${fileExtension}`);
  
      crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function (err, raw) {
  
        cb(null, raw.toString('hex') + Date.now() + fileExtension);
  
      });
  
    },
  
  });

  var mul_upload = multer({dest: './uploads/albums',storage});
  
  app.post('/upload-image-album/:id', [md_auth.ensureAuth, mul_upload.single('image')], AlbumController.uploadImage);


//Rutas
router.get('/home', ProjectController.home);
router.post('/test', ProjectController.test);
router.post('/save-project', ProjectController.saveProject);
router.get('/project/:id?', ProjectController.getProject);
router.get('/projects', ProjectController.getProjects);
router.put('/project/:id', ProjectController.updateProject);

router.post('/upload-image/:id', mul_upload, ProjectController.uploadImage);
router.get('/get-image/:image', ProjectController.getImageFile);

module.exports = router;
```

Tengo otro archivos en mi backend

**app.js**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**index.js**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Gracias por su tiempo.**

Comment: Antes funcionaba?. Si estas instalando en otro lugar prueba hacer `npm install` para que se descarguen de nuevo todas las dependencias.

Comment: No, es la primera vez que lo instalo lo instale en la carpeta de archivo de mi backend desde la consola.